# Proving recursive enumerability of valid formulas without completeness

Tags: logic

[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9309/in-model-theory-does-compactness-easily-imply-completeness) Andreas Blass wrote:

> I think of the completeness theorem as being mainly the conjunction of two quite separate facts. One is compactness. The other is the recursive enumerability of the set of valid formulas (in a recursive vocabulary).

Can one prove the recursive enumerability of the set of valid formulas without first proving completeness?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I know that. This doesn't answer my question at all. :-)

Comment: @JeanMarie Typo. :)

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way of proving that the set of first-order validities is r.e. without (essentially) proving the completeness theorem itself. This stands in stark contrast with the compactness theorem, which can be proved without going through the completeness theorem in any sense.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks!

Comment: Recursive enumerability of the set of valid sentences can be deduced from a version of Herbrand's theorem. (That version effectively produces, for any first-order sentence $A$, an infinite sequence of quantifier-free formulas $A_n$ such that $A$ is valid iff some $A_n$ is a propositional tautology.) But one could argue that this version of Herbrand's theorem is essentially the completeness theorem (and one could also argue that it is not).